# Lightweight inline / in-context content editor for rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system

I have a site that has some areas of content that need to be updated regularly by a copywriter.  I would like to use something light like CushyCMS or somehow include the editable function of Locomotive or BrowserCMS, however it's already an app and I can't go restructuring the pages entirely and content appropriately for a full blow CMS right now.

Again, I'm simply wanting to make about 3 pages editable such that someone will be able to pop on, change or tweak a paragraph or two ***inline*** and then be done.

***What options exist to accomplish something like this for Rails?***  The views are currently HAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mercury editor: http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/
There's even a screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor

Answer (score 8):

Checkout Phrasing, it's a Ruby gem. It can be installed very quickly and allows you to edit text content on the website without breaking layout.

http://infinum.github.io/phrasing/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look through the Ruby Toolbox for a list of available options

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_in_place_editing

Answer (score 0):

I think you could go with a couple of options -

Here is an engine that is a cms - so you can add it to your app, if you are using a modern rails version:

https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa

Back in the day, I used to use comatose for this, but I haven't tried the new rails 3+ version:

https://github.com/darthapo/comatose

Or you could use a service like copycopter:

https://copycopter.com/

(or an open source version, but I have no idea how it compares)

https://github.com/jellybob/text_tractor